# Send boolean to Parse

Tags: parse-platform, restsharp

In Parse I have a class that has a string and a boolean column.
I want to update the object with new values and I do this:

```
RestSharp client =...
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.PUT);
request.AddParameter("String column", "new string");
request.AddJsonBody("{"+"Boolean column"+":False\"}");
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
var requestHandler = client.ExecuteAsync(...)
```

The response's status is OK and when I check with Parse dashboard on the server, the first column has changed. But the second column, the boolean one has not changed.
How should I set the boolean parameter?

I tried:

```
request.AddJsonBody("{"+"Boolean column"+":false\"}");
request.AddJsonBody("{"+"Boolean column"+":0\"}");
```

but none of them changed the value on the backend server.
When I tried:

```
request.AddParameter("Boolean column": false);
```

I got this error:
"{\"code\":111,\"error\":\"schema mismatch for ...; expected Boolean but got String\"}"

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

check your mongodb collection 'SCHEMA' for the answer

---

Because the Parse will create a restricted condition according to the first record inserted for each collection.